# how to use "POST" method to send json data to a url with an authorization?

Tags: c#, json, http

I know it sounds complicated, and I haven't done this before. 
I am trying to create registrant in goto meeting website using their API. Their document requires I use "POST" method send request to url    https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/73563532324/webinars/89541144741
with **json** data that combined of registrant info
There is also an authorization: OAuth oauth_token=XXXXXXXX I don't know how to send it in c#. They suggest me don't use jQuery, but use server-side code. Please help if you know how.

Hope I made this question clear.

A sample code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, you downvoted two of the smartest programmers in the world without even commenting. Nice.

Comment: Wow, "two of the smartest programmers in the world" couldn't be bothered to offer a small code sample to help the OP. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my answer is not in C#, but in the event the OP can use it as a reference point to call the CITRIX API via PHP to register a new GotoWebinar attendee, I'm offering this snippet as a possible solution:

First, we'll need the Organizer Key and Access Token data for our account...

```
    $organizer_key= '10000000000XXXXXXX';
    $access_token = 'GwsiiPWaJbHIiaIiocxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Then, we get the minimum required fields for a webinar (for example from an HTML form) and JSON encode the data...

```
    $newRegFields = (object) array(
        'firstName' => $_POST[ 'FirstName' ],
        'lastName'  => $_POST[ 'LastName'  ],
        'email'     => $_POST[ 'Email'     ],
    );

    $newRegistrantFields = json_encode( $newRegFields );

    //echo '<br><br>' . $newRegistrantFields;
```

And get the Webinar...

```
    $webinarID = preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/", "", $_POST[ "WebinarKey" ] );
```

Set the URL to the CITRIX API (the *resendConfirmation* option is not required)...

```
    $gtw_url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/" . $organizer_key . "/webinars/" . $webinarID . "/registrants?resendConfirmation=false";
```

Format our POST headers...

```
    $headers = array(
        "HTTP/1.1",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=$access_token",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen( $newRegistrantFields )
    );
```

Set our CURL options, ensuring we specify a POST with **CURLOPT_POST, 1** ...

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $gtw_url                       );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers                );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0                   );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1                   );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1                             );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $newRegistrantFields    );

    $newRegistrants = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
```

Our CURL call has returned with JSON encoded data, whether it's a server error message or a confirmation of registration. Now let's turn the reply into a handy associative array...

```
    $newRegistrantsArray = json_decode( $newRegistrants, true );

    //echo '<br><br>' . $newRegistrants . '<br><br>';
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r( $newRegistrantsArray ); echo '</pre>';
```

If the **errorCode** key was returned, then the registration bombed out. All I'm doing here is grabbing the actual error description from the server and loading it up to return to my calling HTML page, but this is totally optional...

```
    if( array_key_exists( 'errorCode', $newRegistrantsArray )) {
        $form_data[ 'status' ] = false;
        $form_data[ 'code'   ] = $newRegistrantsArray[ 'description' ];
        $form_data[ 'error'  ] = 'E200';
        //echo json_encode( $form_data );
        //exit;
    }
```

Now, if a registration was successful, the server will return something like...

```
(
  [registrantKey] => 2.5022062212198E+18
  [joinUrl] => https://global.gotowebinar.com/join/6552167171182613761/103193261
)
```

...and so I'm just checking to see if those keys were returned, and if so, I know the registration was good.

```
    if( array_key_exists( 'registrantKey', $newRegistrantsArray ) && array_key_exists( 'joinUrl', $newRegistrantsArray ) ) {
        $form_data[ 'status' ] = true;
        $form_data[ 'code'   ] = $_POST[ 'Email' ] . ' successfully registered with webinar';
        $form_data[ 'error'  ] = 'E300';
        //echo json_encode( $form_data );
        //exit;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). Set the *Content-Type* and *Authorization* [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) and perform the request using the [UploadString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5c3tz4.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

You could take a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) classes which allows you to send HTTP requests.